# Docker: "not found" for an existing file

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an existing binary file in a Docker container.

Files in current folder:

```
$ ls .
app  Dockerfile  run.sh
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY . /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh && chmod +x /app/app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
./app
ls
```

(The `ls` command is used to check if the `app` not exists)

Build command and outputs:

```
$ sudo docker build . -t app_test
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.427MB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/5 : COPY . /app/
 ---> 4c69dfe88b2e
Step 3/5 : RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh && chmod +x /app/app
 ---> Running in 0dbdc9045827
Removing intermediate container 0dbdc9045827
 ---> 9193aeee2c8f
Step 4/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 9ecb2ad7c3f1
Removing intermediate container 9ecb2ad7c3f1
 ---> 1c748d0cb0b2
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
 ---> Running in 24ebb7500202
Removing intermediate container 24ebb7500202
 ---> adcd6e94a37f
Successfully built adcd6e94a37f
Successfully tagged app_test:latest
```

Run command:

```
$ sudo docker run -it app_test
./run.sh: line 2: ./app: not found
Dockerfile  app         run.sh
```

From the output of `ls` command, we can find `app` exists, but it seems `sh` cannot find it.

I also tried run `./app` directly or use `["sh", "run.sh"]` instead in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, but it doesn't help.

EDIT: This `app` is a closed source software and only a compiled executable is distributed. I'm sorry I cannot provide more information.

Comment: Does it work if you change to, say, `FROM ubuntu:18.04`?  (There are technical reasons it might.)

Comment: You can try to add `.` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: That should be working What are the contents of the app? Is it by any chance a bash script starting with `#!/bin/bash` ? Can you try using `sh app` instead of `./app` in run.sh? You can also debug your container with `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/sh app_test` and try running your app manually do debug the problem

Comment: Are you sure you can run app from alpine? They use a custom libc, which can pose problems. Did you try `./app` as entry point? You should use @mlameiras's solution to troubleshoot this point (actually running app).

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `app` is a shell script, then the error refers to the first line of that script, e.g. `#!/bin/bash` if `/bin/bash` doesn't exist locally. Can also be windows linefeeds breaking that line.

If `app` is an executable, then the error is from linked libraries. Use `ldd app` to see what that binary is linked against. With alpine, the issue is often glibc.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time - `dos2unix` soled the issue. thanks!

Comment: For Golang, using "CGO_ENABLED=0" environment variable  with "go build" command solve the issue.