# Docker for Windows ENTRYPOINT - no such file exists, even though it does

Tags: windows, docker

EDIT: I have re-edited my original post to remove some of the fluff and questions I was asking. I managed to solve this myself, see my answer below

I just had weirdest thing happen to my Docker. Docker images that I build using the command `DOCKER BUILD` are now erroring when I run them as a container saying that the files that in the `ENTRYPOINT` cannot be found.

```
[FATAL tini (7)] exec /bin/start_vsftpd.sh failed: No such file or directory
```

These images are not MINE, they are GIT repos from GITHUB which 100% work and I have ran them several times in the past without issue. Now it errors saying the files do not exist even though they do.

[image]

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Comment: [FATAL tini (7)] exec /bin/start_vsftpd.sh failed: No such file or directory

Comment: if I google for similar issues, the general consenus is that the file is for a different architecture. This is why I think it might be related to windows, like Docker sees it as a windows file and doesn't convert it to linux. Something like that

Comment: shell scripts don't have an architecture they're just text.  Though windows is quirky so I can't speak to that.  What does the shebang line of the shell script look like and does the program it invokes exist?

Comment: Sorry, I am a linux noob, don't know what you mean there.

Comment: top of the shell script starts with `#!`?  That's a shebang line and tells the computer how to execute the file .

Comment: here it is: #!/bin/sh

Comment: Make sure the file is not saved with windows linefeeds. `/bn/sh` may exist, but `/bin/sh\r` does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770305/596285

Comment: @Mitch, I assume your comment about windows linefeeds doesn't matter if I am running the commands directly in the container? (See new screenshot I've added above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the cause of this, and it was indeed due to Windows!

Oddly, if you get a copy of a repo from GITHUB via the zip file method, then extract it, it keeps the correct *Linux* line feeds intact. If, however, you use the `clone GIT` repo method in Visual Studio code, it seems to create the files with *windows* line feeds.

When `Docker build` runs, it copies the `.sh` file using windows line feeds and this is the cause of the image (and I assume any Linux OS) not being able to seee the `.sh` file.

To fix this, before building the image you need to edit the .sh file and convert the line feed to `LF` rather than what Windows selects as the default -  `CRLF`. This shoulf fix the issue, however, I would also advise changing this for all files. I believe there is an option in Visual Studio code to turn this on for all files (just google it).

[image]

Comment: This behavior can be controlled by git configuration https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Comment: Been banging my head for hours. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mucker's answer helped me (thank you!), adding this as an answer instead of a comment because comments do not allow images.

Just wanted to add that notepad++ has a convenient converter to quickly and easily change all those line endings:

[image]